# Rails with postgres - activerecord query: sort by column ASC, then group by column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model Laps, which belongs to :Car

So each car has many laps, but I need to do a query where i pull in the top 10 fastest Laps, but only pull in the fastest lap per each car. In other words, I do not want one car to be allowed to have 5 of the top 10 fastest laps in the list.

Each lap has a :car_id field. I want to group on this column, and then pull out the lap with the min(Lap.time) row from the grouping. (AKA fastest lap time from that unique :car_id).

So with Postgres, what is my best approach to this? Can I order all laps first, then group, and then pull the first from the group. Or will grouping not keep the sort order?

Here is my schema for the Lap Model:

```
  create_table "laps", force: true do |t|
    t.decimal  "time"
    t.string   "video_url"
    t.integer  "car_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "approved"
  end
```

Do I have to use two combined queries for this?

I can get a unique car id's lap by doing this:

```
select('DISTINCT ON (car_id) *')
```

but, I need to order the laps so that it gets the min(lap.time) per that car_id. So when i throw on an order like this:

```
select('DISTINCT ON (car_id) *').order('car_id, time ASC').sort_by! {|ts| ts.time}
```

This works, but seems like an odd way to go about it. As soon as i try and change around the order, like removing the car_id from the order, i get postgres errors.

Comment: Maybe this? `Lap.select('min(laps.time), laps.*').group('laps.id, laps.car_id').limit(10)`

Comment: I just tried this. It gives me multiple laps from the same car_id

Comment: This is what I did and its working to get the unique car_id's fastest, but when I debug the object it is not sorted by time it seems. If there is a better way to go about these please post your answer:

    select('DISTINCT ON (car_id) *').order('car_id, time ASC')

Answer (score 4):

As you're discovering, DISTINCT ON isn't going to work for you here because it doesn't match the first term you want to sort on (time).  You'll need to use a GROUP BY:

```
Lap.group(:car_id).limit(10).minimum(:time)
```

Alternatively, you can make a windowed subquery - but that is quite a bit messier to build.  If you need the actual lap information aside for the time, you may have to go that route:

```
subquery = Lap.select('lap.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY car_id ORDER BY time, car_id ) as rowNum').to_sql
Lap.scoped.from(Arel.sql("(#{subquery}) fast_laps"))
   .where('rowNum = 1')
   .order('time, car_id')
   .limit(10)
```

Comment: I tried this already, but I get: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions. Do I need to change my select order or something as well?

Comment: @JoelGrannas, right - this isn't going to work.  Updated with alternative answer.

Comment: I do need the lap information (time, id, mph, video_url). Can you elaborate on the windowed subquery or provide that method

Comment: How do you think the subquery would be performance wise compared to my answer below with the resorting?

Comment: @JoelGrannas - for small amounts of data it won't matter much.  For large amounts of data (several hundred rows) the subquery will outperform significantly since it won't need to transfer every `car_id` record to be created and sorted in ActiveRecord.  For even larger amounts, the windowing will slow down somewhat as well - you'll probably need to change the subquery to use GROUP BY to make use of the indexes, and use the outer query to fetch the the entire row of data.  But that likely won't happen until you're near the 1 million row mark.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and its working. If there is a better way to go about these please post your answer:

in my model:

```
def self.fastest_per_car
    select('DISTINCT ON (car_id) *').order('car_id, time ASC').sort_by! {|ts| ts.time}
end
```

Comment: I'd stay away from the sort_by! and having ruby do the heavy loading your db should take care of